# How to change foreign-key in many to one relationship without fetching it

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

Assume that we have a many to one relationship in hibernate. **Book** entity can have just one **Author** and an **Author** can have many **Books**.

**Book entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="books")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToOne
    private Author author;
}
```

**Author entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "authors")
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
    private List<Book> books;

    public void addBook(Book book){
        if (books == null)
            books = new ArrayList<Book>();

        books.add(book);
        book.setAuthor(this);
    }
}
```

I persisted some books and authors in session1. Now every book has FK to an author and session is closed. Now in a new session I want to change PK of a book without fetching that book. I know id of book and I want to update just its FK to another Author. Something like this:

```
Author getAuthor = session2.get(Author.class, 1L);
Book tmpBook = new Book();
tmpBook.setId(2L);
tmpBook.setAuthor(getAuthor);
session2.update(tmpBook);
```

But in this scenario hibernate updates all other columns of book to NULL. This is not what I want. I don't want to fetch book at first and then change PK of it. Is there any solution for this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think that Hibernate does not updates data but inserts new book entity. Have you checked that book (assuming the one inserted in session1) isn't still present? Updating PK is not a good idea, it sounds rather like a very bad practice.

Comment: @soulcoder I didn't update PK. Notice that 2L id in Book entity existed before in database. I just set PK in tmpBook to select existed book with id of 2L and just update its FK to a new Author(getAuthor in sample code)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd have to use a query for that and can't do it as you tried, hibernate needs the entity fetched to update it, otherwise its treated as a transient object

Comment: @RezaHedayati this is really wrong way you try to do it. Why do not you just fetch the entity and do it 'by the book' accordingly to Hibernate flow?